# Route Subnet to Interface

Tags: linux-networking

Can somebody plz tell me whats wrong with my setup? I need a virtual 10.0.0.x subnet with internet to install vm.

the guest setup is:

```
ip 10.0.0.3
nm 255.255.255.0
gw 10.0.0.2 (also tried 10.0.0.1)
```

:(

```
#source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 153.9.147.85
        netmask 255.255.255.254
        gateway 153.9.147.65
        pointopoint 153.9.147.65
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp2s0/proxy_arp

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.2
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

#        post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
#        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:3d:7e:f8:f0:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 153.9.147.85 peer 153.9.147.65/32 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d63d:7eff:fef8:f067/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:c4:7e:30:b3:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/22 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::70c4:7eff:fe30:b3c7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

```
ip route
default via 153.9.147.65 dev enp2s0 onlink 
10.0.0.0/22 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
10.0.0.1 via 153.9.147.65 dev enp2s0 
10.0.0.2 via 153.9.147.65 dev enp2s0 
153.9.147.65 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 153.9.147.85
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         153.9.147.65    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
10.0.0.1        153.9.147.65    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0
10.0.0.2        153.9.147.65    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0
153.9.147.65    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp2s0
```

```
# ping -I vmbr0 www.example.com
PING www.example.com (93.184.216.34) from 10.0.0.2 vmbr0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.example.com ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 235ms
pipe 4
```

---

As expected its just the internet routing (https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5O4B.png) also not working with:

```
root@vms ~ # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
root@vms ~ # iptables -A FORWARD -i vmbr0 -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
root@vms ~ # iptables -A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o vmbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? Your hypervisor should create the virtual network itself.

Comment: The hoster of the cloud (dedicated server) don't allow up/download of vm. So i can not transfer them from and to my private proxmox installation at home. Thats why i orderd dedicated box and they have preinstalled proxmox but without bridge/router presetup.

Comment: Is it already working for somebody?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Your hosting company can't prevent you from uploading or downloading anything, and it would be a totally useless service if they tried.

Comment: Man, nobody cares about the hosting company and they are free to offer whatever service they want.

Comment: Did you come here to get help with your problem or to engage in useless arguments?

Comment: the point is, i'm pretty sure that a connection 10.0.0.3 to 10.0.0.4 is working from vm to vm, which i'm going to test after i downloaded the full installation image and not using the netinstall. So there is something very small missing to route the frame which does not fit the netmask from the vmbr0 bridge to the 153.9.147.65 gateway on enp2s0.

Comment: Probably NAT. But again you need to set that up in Proxmox.